# Form not displaying as expected

Tags: html, css, forms

Am working on a form which has 5 input fields and one submit button is expected to be display as two rows and three columns with the form fields.
Am getting output like first two input fields are displaying properly in first row but the other three elements are broken.

```
My code:

<div id="form_div">
<form id="fm_form">
  <label>
      Date1<br />
      <input id="nn" name="dd" type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
     Date2<br />
       <input id="kk" name="ff" type="text" />
  </label>
    <label>
    Vehicle<br />
    <select id="dd" style="">
      <option value="null">--text--</option>
    </select>
    </label>

    <label>
    Name<br />
    <select id="name" style="">
    <option value="null">--Name--</option>
    </select>
    </label>

    <label>
  Location<br />
  <select id="location" style="">
    <option value="null">--Location--</option>
  </select>
  </label>
  <label>
  <br />
  <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </label>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Css:

```
#fm_form label
{
display:block;
float:left;
margin-right:21px;
vertical-align:top;
width: 210px;
/*padding:25px;*/
}

#fm_form input[type=text]  
{

height: 25px;
width: 210px;
}

#fm_form input[type=submit]
{

height: 30px;
width: 210px;
}


#fm_form select
{

height: 30px;
width: 210px;
}

#form_div, #fm_form{

height: 154px;
width: 696px;
border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using floats. You need to clear them when you are start a new row.
Insert the following inbetween the two rows:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

I'd also suggest reading [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for further reading on floats, and how to clear them.

Comment: Also am facing a problem in the same form ie, i cannot adjust the height of the input-box in this form .Could you please help me out of this?

Comment: Are you referring to all `input[type=text]` elements when you say input-box?

Comment: no only.. text box.actually i can change height of select box and all...but text-box not working

Comment: You can style a `textarea` element the same as you can an `input` element

Comment: Also the form display properly now, but the select box have different width even though i set the width as 210px.I belive it is because the text-box are taking automatic width and height..how can i set the wdith and height of textbox?

Comment: The `select` elements may be slightly different in size due to margins or padding, try setting both of these to 0. As for the `textarea`, which is what I assume you mean by textbox, you should be able to set the width and height using `height: 10em; width: 10em;`